# Is smart/fuzzy searching possible in CiviCRM?

Tags: database, search

I'm not sure what the feature is called, but Google seems to collapse all accented letters to their base character when indexing. So a search for "Nandor" will find a record "Nándor". But searching my Civi database for the unaccented name finds no results.
Is there a setting (either in CiviCRM or MySQL) or a plugin that would make such searches work?

Comment: Well, if I add a test contact named Nándor in http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and do a normal search from `Find Contact` with string `Nandor`, the created contact do get returned in the search result.

Answer (score 2):

This feature exists. It is part of MySQL and called *collation*. You can read about the background on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-effect.html .

In my test database a search on *Nandor* returns *Nándor*. Reason `last_name` column is defined as

```
 `last_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Last Name.'
```

and the collation `utf8_unicode_ci` defines them to be the same.

Altering the setting with

```
ALTER TABLE civicrm_contact MODIFY last_name varchar(64) COLLATE latin1_bin;
```

has the effect that they are not considered the same anymore.

What is your collation setting?